# How to serialize non-associated models?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, serialization

I have two models that are not associated.

Both models use their own serializer.

In model 1, I have a method that makes a call to model 2.

I'd like to serialize that call in model 1, so it returns a collection from model 2, but for the collection to be serialized using model 2's custom serializer.

Right now it ends up using the Rails default serializer rather than the custom serializer I have defined.

Is there a way to force it to use my custom serializer?

=============

EXAMPLE CODE:

```
class ModelOne < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes :id, :name, :all_model_two

  def all_model_two
    object.get_all_model_two
  end
end

class ModelTwo < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes :id, :name
end
```

The method 'get_all_model_two' is specified on the ModelOne model.

Comment: Can you paste your current serializer?  The right answer depends which serializer class you're using, e.g. rabl, ActiveModel::Serializer, etc...

Comment: I'm using active model serializer

Comment: Can you paste some code?

Comment: Ok, I added an example. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out how to do it.

I needed to wrap my method call like such:

```
def all_model_two
  object.get_all_model_two.active_model_serializer.new(object.get_all_model_two)
end
```